# Set row as static/fixed (unsortable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I have a sortable table in which I would like to have a certain row fixed to the top of the table, unaffected by sorting filters.

I have looked for a way to tag the row as "non-sortable" but it seems there are only 2 ways to sort rows - acending or descending by column value. There is no option to fix a row.

I have tried to yank the row out and insert it at the top using jQuery, which works fine. The problem though is that I am also using a Fixed Column plugin, which relies on the sorting from the datatable. 
This ultimately leads to my homemade jQuery fix messing up the Fixed Column badly.

My question is, is there a way to set the row as static, so that it is never sorted, or can I somehow manipulate the sorting of the datatable to keep the row at the top of the table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

The Grid jQuery widget by Shield UI supports making a column non-sortable.

A live demo can be seen [here](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/sorting).

Comment: The question is not about making the column non-sortable but keeping the row at the top of the table with jQuery DataTables.